# How can I pass ESLint recommended to package.json?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

According to http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring I can pass an `eslintConfig` object in package.json with my config in it. I just want to pass the standard ESLint recommended preset. How can I do that within that object?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```